# Develop Google Apps Script Project in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, google-apps-script

Somebody knows how to develop a Google Apps Script project in Netbeans 8?

I only found the way to connect with Eclipse in https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/apps_script.

But nothing about Netbeans

tnx

Comment: Good question.  Someone would probably need to develop an add-on for Netbeans that uses the Google Drive SDK to import and export Apps Script Projects.  [Import/Export Script Projects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/import-export)

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for Netbeans, but you can build your own integration using the [Import/Export functionality](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/import-export) and the Drive API.